# IBM Rational License Key

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

I have Returned all clearcase and ClearQuest license from a server m1 and have imported new licenses, but i still see the old licenses when i open license key administrator.

As said before these licenses were returned to the pool and are being utilized by another machine m2

[image]
In the image, i want to remove the highlighted entries.

How can i remove the old license entries from the machine m1? any help?

Answer (score 2):

Since LKAD is not telling you "served by..." these licenses are in the local license files. On Windows, those files are:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalRLKS\common\rational_server_perm.dat
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalRLKS\common\rational_server_temp.dat

The licenses you import will overwrite ONE of those files depending on the type of licenses you import.

The simplest thing to do is to go into the files in question and delete the INCREMENT blocks you want to get rid of. They're just text files.

An increment block looks like this.

```
INCREMENT ClearCase rational 1.00000 15-jan-2015 10 {redacted} \
    VENDOR_STRING="0|Floating|0| ClearCase:1.0" DUP_GROUP=U \
    vendor_info="0|IBM Rational ClearCase Floating License Key \
    (FLEXlm license manager)|0" ISSUED=02-jun-2014 NOTICE="Sales \
    Order Number: {redacted}" ck={redacted} SN={redacted}
```

You need to get rid of the whole block, and not just the INCREMENT line.

Comment: +1. If they are local licenses, the "Client/server configuration" isn't the issue.

Comment: Well, for **ClearCase** anyway, you have to have a license server because the application required "floating" licenses.

Answer (score 0):

I remember in one instance having to uninstall and reinstall the license manager, in order to properly reset the keys.

- First try and [configure your license server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_config_licensing.htm), by managing the list of license servers.
- Try and reconfigure the [Rational License Key Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rational/v0r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.license.doc/topics/t_setup_rcl.html).
  Menu `Settings => Client/Server configuration`

[image: setting]

- Make sure you have [properly updated the license file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.licensing.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_update_lic_file.htm)

And it can depend on your version of ClearCase/ClearQuest, and their associated license manager.

For 8+, it uses the IBM Rational® License Key Administrator (LKAD), which provides an interface to IBM Rational Common Licensing (powered by Flexera software).